# JMeter view log file in viewer

Tags: logging, jmeter

So I run a Jmeter job on an Ubuntu server via the CLI. The test has a "View Results Tree" where I provide a log filename and path. I then can "less" cmd and scroll but wow is that tedious. I want to know if it is possible to download that log file and load it in JMeter Gui and view as you would in the View Results Tree element? Or does anyone know of some kind of JMeter Gui log viewer that can be used?

So I see I did not explain this correctly. Let me add that the running of the test is in the past. Now I have the tree log file in XML. I am looking for a tool that takes that XML and makes it into a pretty interface like the JMeter TREE log viewer while running the test but in this case AFTER the test is completed.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can view that in GUI by browsing the file.
Please bear in mind - by default, it will not allow you view all the samples. If you wanted to view all teh samples then you need to enable the configuration in
/bin/jmeter.properties and set the max_results to 0

```
view.results.tree.max_results=0
```

I am not aware of any external tool to view the results - you can give it a try with Octoperf

Answer (score 0):

1. You can mount the folder from the Ubuntu server where the listener is writing results to via [NFS](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/NFS) or [Samba](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-samba-share-for-a-small-organization-on-ubuntu-16-04) so it will be available over the network
2. You can copy the file from the Ubuntu server using [scp](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-use-scp-command-to-securely-transfer-files/) command to yur local machine and open the file using JMeter GUI
3. You can use [SSH X forwarding](https://tldp.org/HOWTO/XDMCP-HOWTO/ssh.html) and run JMeter on the Ubuntu server and see its GUI on your local machine (you will need to have [X server](https://www.x.org/archive/X11R7.7/doc/man/man1/Xserver.1.xhtml) up and running on your machine)
4. If you just added [View Results Tree](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener and provided the path to the file where the metrics will be stored - you won't be able to see request and response details. You will need to press "Configure" button and choose what do you want to store:

   [image]

   alternatively you can amend [JMeter Properties which are responsible for the results file configuraiton](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#results_file_config), you can choose what is stored in JMeter's [.jtl results file](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/jmeter/JtlFiles). More information: [How to Save Response Data in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/response-data-in-jmeter)